# Angular 17 : Inspect does not show the initiator

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

I am using Angular 11 in VSCode. When running using `npm start` I was able to do a inspect on the rendered view and find the initiator in the network tab.

When published in production this initiator in the network tab used to show either polyfills.js or vendor.js for all calls.

However, when I have upgraded from 11--> 12 --> 13 --> 14 --> 15 --> 16 --> 17, run the code in VSCode using `npm start` the initiator in the network tab  shows either polyfills.js or vendor.js for all calls as opposed to Angular 11.

Now it is really taking a very long time for me to reach the initiator point.

Can anyone help me on how I can overcome this and get the initiator in the network tab shown as the actual value (as in Angular 11)?

Comment: You probably didn't build your v11 app in prod mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case use `"sourceMap": true,`

in `angular.json` file wherever you have build

Refer the image for more info :

[image: Click Here to see the Image]

Note : make sure you have to re run you application with *ng serve*